# How to set defalut value in CGridView

Tags: yii, cgridview

How can I set default value if `$data->pic==""` in my dataprovider values. Set data pic as `na.jpg`

```
widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'type'=>'raw',
        'name'=>'pic',
        'value'=>'CHtml::image("http://localhost/studentpics/".$data->pic)',
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'columns'=>array(
 array(
                    'name'=>'your Image URL',
                    'type'=>'image',
                    'htmlOptions'=>array('width'=>'30px','height'=>'30px'),
            ),
));
```

Answer (score 1):

`value` is evaluated as a php expression so it is ok to use a condition in it

```
'value'=>'CHtml::image(($data->pic)?"http://localhost/studentpics/".$data->pic:"default_image_url")',
```

P.S it's a bad idea to use absolute url's everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can override  afterFind method of CActiveRecord

```
protected function afterFind()
{
 if($this->pic ===null)
   {
    $this->pic = na.jpg;
   }
  parent::afterFind();
}
```